# Storing SQL output in an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to fetch the SQL output into an array. I have the following codes.

```
require 'connect.inc.php';

$query = "
SELECT  `OS_NoSpecies`
     ,  `OS_ShWeiner` 
     ,  `OS_NoTropSpec`
     ,  `OS_NoTropGen` 
     ,  `OS_PropDetr` 
     , `OS_PropBenthic`
     ,  `OS_PropEstSpawn` 
  FROM bmoffshore AS b 
     , boundedmetric AS bmc
 WHERE b.BM_Code = bmc.BM_Code
   AND bmc.bm_year =  '2013' 
   AND bmc.bm_season = 'Summer' 
";

if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {

while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
    $OS_NoSpecies = $query_row['OS_NoSpecies'];
    $OS_ShWeiner = $query_row['OS_ShWeiner'];
    $OS_NoTropSpec = $query_row['OS_NoTropSpec'];
    $OS_NoTropGen = $query_row['OS_NoTropGen'];
    $OS_PropDetr = $query_row['OS_PropDetr'];
    $OS_PropBenthic = $query_row['OS_PropBenthic'];
    $OS_PropEstSpawn = $query_row['OS_PropEstSpawn'];       

echo $OS_NoSpecies. ' '.$OS_ShWeiner. ' '.$OS_NoTropSpec. ' '.$OS_NoTropGen. ' '.$OS_PropDetr. ' '.$OS_PropBenthic.' '.$OS_PropEstSpawn.'<br>';     
}
} else {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Basically, the SQL output as following (4 rows and 7 columns):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 4 5 2 8 4 6 
6 9 4 9 2 4 5
2 0 9 5 9 6 7
```

But What I am actually trying to output is one array for each row: Example:

```
1st array (array1) containg all row values of  1st row
2nd array (array2) containg all row values of  2nd row
3rd array (array3) containg all row values of  3rd row
4th array (array4) containg all row values of  4th row
```

i'll be thankful for the help pls.

Comment: Please Try with "mysql_fetch_array"                                             while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) {

Answer (score 0):

What I just did is, created an variable of array and have entered the values into it on every iteration, not sure if this is what you expect as final resultant array

```
if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
    $resultArray = array();
    while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
        $resultArray[] = $query_row;
    }
}
```

to check values you should make use of `var_dump($query_row);` or `var_dump($resultArray);`